# Java8 update60 no longer works with IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I recently updated my JRE to Java8 update60, after that I found the applet no longer works in IE (version 8,9,10,11).

After some debugging I found the reason is **document.getElementById('ExplorerApplet').isActive();** cannot be invoked. **isActive()** is a public method from Applet.class, which we used to detect if the applet is alive.

I have checked the release notes from Oracle, no useful information is found. And I also tried to replace the **applet** tag with **object** ,failed either. Can anyone give some idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.**

The reason is the applet container is a "hidden" element, remove this attribute then all work fine. I don't know why the behavior changes for the new java plug-in, and it is not documented in the release notes.